# How do I rebind the "Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed" to left click?

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, cinnamon

I am on Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit and I want to show highlight the pointer when I press click, to highlight the mouse in recordings. I tried `KeyMon` for this but it is pretty buggy: the highlight does not fade out if you move the cursor and the highlight can't go everywhere on the screen (such as the taskbar, or on the far left).

The option to show pointer when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> looks pretty much like I want, but I want to rebind it to left click instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>. Also, I'd like for the effect not to be activated when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> so I can use <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>, etc without showing the effect (so making the left click also trigger <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is not the ideal solution).

So is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to rebind the key but we could solve this problem using two command line tools. Considering that the pointer animation is showed when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, we can automate the process of pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> just after you left-click the mouse. That's possible using `cnee` and `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt install cnee xdotool
```

If you run the following line of code on a terminal window you will see the same animation that you see pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> when you left-click the mouse:

```
cnee --record --mouse | awk  '/7,5,0,0,1/ { system("xdotool keydown ctrl keyup ctrl") }'
```

**Result:**

[image]

OBS: Pressing <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL+ ANY CHARACTER</kbd> does not activate the pointer animation. So the left-click triggering the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key can be a solution...